# Do you have to perform assist abilities?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

Most assists are worded as if they are required to be performed.  Do they *have* to be if at all possible?

For instance, the Backdoor card says

> Cancel all abilities on one obstacle for the rest of the game

If I then have only one obstacle left and it's description says that a runner gets 1 HP healed once it's defeated, does this have to be canceled?  The card doesn't say "You may cancel all abilities" but this seems like the sort of thing that would be a deck wide ruling, such as the runner not being required to apply all damage from the cards they play.

Comment: If you provide an example of what situation you are asking about it would help answer the question.

Comment: Updated the main question with an example

Answer (score 1):

**No.** You do not *have* to use your assist cards. They are optional. The text on the cards is what happens if you *choose* to use them, not rules that enter play once the card is drawn.